# Possible Bug with Options in DelaunayMesh

Tags: bugs, graphics3d, computational-geometry, mesh

**Bug introduced in 10.2 and persisting through 11.1**

---

**Update**:

It turns out after some testing, none of the `Options` work in `DelaunayMesh` when 3D point sets are involved.

**Original**

In *Mathematica* 10.2 the new `Option` `MeshCellHighlight` and updated `Option` `MeshCellStyle` does not seem to work when used in `DelaunayMesh` of `3D` point sets. For example, the following does nothing.

```
pts = RandomReal[5, {40, 3}];
del = DelaunayMesh[pts, MeshCellHighlight -> {{2, All} -> Yellow}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But for 2D point sets we get the expected result:

```
pts2d = RandomReal[5, {40, 2}];
del2d = DelaunayMesh[pts2d, MeshCellHighlight -> {{2, All} -> Yellow, {1, All} -> 
                      Directive[Thick, Dashed, Red]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also it works with `ConvexHullMesh`:

```
ConvexHullMesh[pts, MeshCellHighlight -> {{2, All} -> Yellow}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From the documentation of `DelaunayMesh`:

> DelaunayMesh takes the same options as MeshRegion.

So we can do

```
MeshRegion[del, MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> Yellow}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course, one can just use `HighlightMesh` afterwards on `del` to achieve the desired result. I have tried this on both **Windows** and **Linux**. Can anyone confirm these results?

Comment: Reported internally as a bug. Thank you!

Comment: @ilian. Thanks for reporting it.